# Do return false; halt the script in user defined functions (PHP)

Tags: php

What does return true; and return false; exactly responds in user defined functions?

```
function valid_image($image, $target, $width, $height = 0) {

        if($image["type"] !== "image/jpeg") {
            alert('File must be of type image/jpeg');
            return false;
        }
        if(file_exists($target.$image['name'])) {
            alert('File Already Exists, Please Choose a Different Name for the File');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
   }
```

Considering the above example if the first condition `if($image["type"] !== "image/jpeg"` returns true. Does the return false; statement right below it stop the script from executing the below code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first statement **evaluated** to true, then the `return false` immediately under it will end the function (I should say alert() will be called first).

Answer (score 1):

No it does not stop script executing, it will just return from the function (stop execution of the function). You should use it in this fashion:

```
function alert($message){
    //display error message to user
}
if(valid_image($_FILES['image'], '/var/www/uploads', 100, 100){
   //valid image
}
else{
   //invalid image
}
```

This is not a good validation function, the 'type' property can easily be spoofed, and is determined by the visitors Operating System. A better function would at least validate the extension, and filter the name.

Comment: Yes it does, "return" stop the execution of the function

Comment: It stops the function, but not whole php script. That's done by `exit()`;

Comment: i am doing the same way, that is not my exact function i just wrote it for demonstration. what i wanted to know is if some condition is returned true or false what does the return true and return false script do with reference to the above function.

Comment: @Lekensteyn i dont want to stop the whole script i just want to stop the function. and i guess my question was does it stop the rest script within the function from executing.

Comment: I interpreted 'the below code' as the code outside the function ('the script' as 'php file')

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar to confirm then, the return statement does stop the rest of the script within the function.

Think of return as 'after this, do no more in the function'.

Comment: @danielgwood thank you, that is the cut and clear statement, i got that. :)