# Do return true; continue the script till end in the same function?

Tags: php

My function goes something like this

```
function multiple_delete($checkbox, $table, $url, $picture1 = 0, $picture2 = 0, $picture3 = 0){
    $count = count($checkbox);
for($j=0;$j<$count;$j++)
    {
    $delete_id = $checkbox[$j];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = '$delete_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return true;

if( $picture1 !== 0 && $picture2 !== 0 && $picture3 !== 0) 
    {
    $pic_1 = $picture1;
    $pic_2 = $picture2;
    $pic_3 = $picture3;
    unlink($pic_1);
    unlink($pic_2);
    unlink($pic_3);
    return true;
    }
if( $picture1 !== 0 && $picture2 !== 0 && $picture3 == 0 ) 
    {
    $pic_1 = $picture1;
    $pic_2 = $picture2;
    unlink($pic_1);
    unlink($pic_2); 
    return true;  
    }
    }

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)   {
    $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id='$del_id'";
    $result_delete_data = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    alert('Deleted Successfully');
    redirect_url($url);
    return true;
    }
```

In the above function if the first or second condition returns true, then will it continue over the for loop below or it will simply halt the script ?

If return true will halt the script then

EDIT: Is it ok if I remove the return statement from the if conditions? And is it necessary for us to define the return statement in a user defined function?

Comment: I don't think the function you wrote will ever do what you want it to do, even if you remove the `return` statements. Go through the function line by line and think about what values the variables have and what it means for the flow. For example it looks like if `$count` is larger than `1`, the same pictures are delted over and over again. Also, you don't seem to do anythin with `$row`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do return false; halt the script in user defined functions (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582863/do-return-false-halt-the-script-in-user-defined-functions-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you use `return` its going to halt the execution of the function and `return`. I think you may be looking for `continue` and/or `break`. Also why do all this with separate queries? I would:

1. Use a `SELECT...WHERE...IN` to grab ALL the matching records for images.
2. Loop through those records and delete the files, putting the primary key values of the images deleted in a second array.
3. Use a `DELETE...WHERE...IN` query to kill all the records.

That way you only hit the db twice. It might look something like the following:

```
function multiple_delete($checkbox, $table, $url, $picture1 = 0, $picture2 = 0, $picture3 = 0){
    $count = count($checkbox);
    $select = sprintf('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id IN (%s)', $table, implode(',',$checkbox));
    $imagesResult = mysql_query($select);
    $deletes = array();
    while(false !== ($record = mysql_fetch_array($imagesResult))
    {

      if( $picture1 !== 0 && $picture2 !== 0 && $picture3 !== 0) 
      {
        $pic_1 = $picture1;
        $pic_2 = $picture2;
        $pic_3 = $picture3;
        unlink($pic_1);
        unlink($pic_2);
        unlink($pic_3);
        continue;
      }
      if( $picture1 !== 0 && $picture2 !== 0 && $picture3 == 0 ) 
      {
        $pic_1 = $picture1;
        $pic_2 = $picture2;
        unlink($pic_1);
        unlink($pic_2); 
        continue;  
      }

      $deletes[] = $record['id'];
    }

    $delete = sprintf('DELETE FROM %s WHERE id IN (%s)', $table, implode(',',$deletes));
    $result_delete_data = mysql_query($delete);

    alert('Deleted Successfully');
    redirect_url($url);

}
```

In the above the `continue`'s are going to move you to the next iteration of the loop if the are processed... Likewise using a `break` instead would stop the loop completely and move on to the next code block where you delete from the DB. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here with the `if` statements that those are in... You might not even need to use `continue`/`break`... Can you could elaborate on what you actually need to do?

The last bit beyond the database stuff doesn't make sense either... I assume your `redirect` function does something with `header` to send them to another page... and if that's the case your function is going to stop when that happens so it doesn't make sense to return any kind of result. Then you do an `alert` and I don't know what you've made that do either but I assume it adds the message to a session variable for the page `redirect` sends them to?

Comment: how do i define continue ? return continue;   or   continue;    can you please define the syntax?

Comment: I would give +2 for the additional notes. Sadly enough, I can't ;)

Answer (score 1):

It will exit the function. The loop won't continue.

You can easily test it:

```
foreach(range(0,10) as $int) {
    if($int > 5) {
        return;
    }
    echo $int . PHP_EOL;
}
```

prints

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: how do i make it continue the script? by defining the return true in the end?

Comment: is it ok if i remove the return statement from the if conditions. ? and is it necessary for us to define the return statement in a user defined function?

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar: Yes, for example. It depends totally on what the function is supposed to do. You don't need to define a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've pasted this correctly, you are never going to execute the if statements since they are following a return statement. I'm guessing you need to rethink that first for loop since you're querying a database, getting a row, then returning true. There's no need for it to be in a loop.

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forloop.php might help.

Answer (score 0):

It will return a the first return statement it comes to. Which in this case is 5 lines into the function...it will never get to the if statements